# Frida +Python+Javascript what does "java.use ("XXX") " do when the class can not be found?

Tags: javascript, python, android, hook, frida

I use the following javascrip inside python (in android + frida environment) to hook a method.

```
jscode ="""
Java.perform(function () { 
    console.log("start hook...");
    var d =java.use("myapp.okhttp3.internal.f.a");
    d.verify.implementation =function(p1, p2){
    console.log("ssl unpinning for"); 
    return true; 
    }
});
"""
```

This is the python file:

```
import sys  
import os  
import threading  
import subprocess  
import frida  
import time


jscode ="""
Java.perform(function () { 
    console.log("start hook...");
    var d =java.use("myapp.okhttp3.internal.f.a");
    d.verify.implementation =function(p1, p2){
    console.log("ssl unpinning for"); 
    return true; 
    }
});
"""  
os.system('adb forward tcp:27042 tcp:27042')  
os.system('adb forward tcp:27043 tcp:27043')  

APP_NAME = 'myapp'   
device = frida.get_usb_device(1)
pid = device.spawn([APP_NAME])  
device.resume(pid)  
time.sleep(1)  
process = device.attach(pid)  
print('success')
script = process.create_script(jscode) 
print(pid) 
script.load() 
print('script loaded') 
input()
```

My question is: Does `var d =java.use("myapp.okhttp3.internal.f.a")`  throw "class not found exception" when the class can not be found, and how to view this exception? can I use codes like **console.log(java.use("myapp.okhttp3.internal.f.a")** to log "class not found exception"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use surround try-catch in js and catch @ handle in python

```js
try {
  var d =...
} catch (e) {
  send(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

In python side

```py
def on_message(msg, _data):
  # check if msg has error and handle

script.on('message', on_message)
```